# How to install "mail"

Tags: email, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to install "mail" on a Red Hat 4.1.2-48 box. I tried:

```
yum install mail
```

It prints out:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.anl.gov
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * ius: mirror.rackspace.com
 * updates: yum.singlehop.com
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00     
epel                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00     
ius                                                      | 2.2 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00     
utterramblings                                           |  951 B     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
No package mail available.
Nothing to do
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: 4.1.2? *Really*?

Comment: ok, figured out that I need to do "yum install mailx" instead. But why am I not getting any email still?

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps you meant `yum install mailx`?

You can test it sends emails using `echo "Test" | mail yourname@domain.tld`

Comment: Thanks Vlad, yes I figured that part out as posted in my comment above. But why am I not receiving the email now? What steps am I missing now? Thanks.

Comment: What MTA are you using? Sendmail, exim?

Comment: It is Sendmail.

Comment: Have a look over the configuration http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/

If everything looks ok, check to see if the messages are bounced by the recipient's server or marked/sent to spam.

Comment: its echo "Body" | mailx "subject" yourmailid